# How to format CSV file for a comma separated list within a CSV file

Tags: csv, etl, export-to-csv

I have a question with the [OneRoster v1.1 CSV format](https://www.imsglobal.org/oneroster-v11-final-csv-tables) I was hoping someone could help clarify. Specifically this is kind of a general question as to how to list comma separated lists within csv files. This question is also posted in the IMS forum here: https://www.imsglobal.org/forum/oneroster-public-forum/199141

For the users.csv file, agentSourcedIds column, the the OneRoster spec says “If multiple IDs are required then use double quotes and separate with commas.” I would like to clarify what this means.

Should it be option 1 or 2?

Option 1: `...,"ID1,ID2",...`

Option 2: `...,"""ID1,ID2""",...`

When Option 1 is interpreted such as opening in Microsoft Excel, it looks like this `ID1,ID2`. For option 2, it will preserve a set of quotes and looks like this `"ID1,ID2"`

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is the correct way. OneRoster follows RFC 4180 in regards to comma separated lists: https://www.imsglobal.org/forum/oneroster-public-forum/199141